# Android Image Capture Pic Quality

Tags: android, image, camera

```
  intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageFileUri);
        ((Activity) mContext). startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

I am using above code to take picture, but the image file size is reduced from what I take using native camera. Is there any way to specify the image size explicitly?

The typical size difference:-
Native camera - 3MB
Using above procedure - 400Kb

Comment: You might be [returning the thumbnail instead of the full-sized image](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html). Could you add more relevant code to your question?

Comment: `the image size`. Do you mean the file size?

Comment: @PPartisan Thumbnail is only when I am getting through onActivityResult. Here I am passing the URI where the image is to be saved.

Comment: @greenapps Yes That is what I meant.

Comment: How are you checking file sizes? You are talking but not showing anything.

Comment: I go to the file manager And check the sizes.(Additional info:- I want to upload the file later)